# Suspend laptop when closing lid

Tags: systemd, power-management, journalctl

My laptop does not suspend when I close the lid. I have the default settings in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, i.e. everything is commented out (uncommenting does not have an effect, as expected):

```
$ grep -i lid /etc/systemd/logind.conf
> #HandleLidSwitch=suspend
> #HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
> #HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
> #LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

Suspicious to me is, that when I look at `journalctl`, and close the lid, I do not see any event message.

Suspending from the command line works just fine.

How can I suspend my laptop when the lid is closed?

Edit: I am on Arch Linux with i3.

```
$ systemd-inhibit --list
> WHO            UID USER PID COMM           WHAT  WHY                                       MODE 
> NetworkManager 0   root 314 NetworkManager sleep NetworkManager needs to turn off networks delay
> 
> 1 inhibitors listed.
```

Edit2: I checked the state of the lid like this:

```
while true; do
    cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
    sleep 1
done
```

Then closed the lid for a while, opened it again. I always got the same output:

```
state:     open
```

Edit 3:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i lid
> [    1.131805] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
> [    1.131837] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
```

Answer (score 2):

**HandleLidSwitch** can take one of these parameters :

```
suspend 
lock 
ignore
poweroff
```

You need to restart logind service so the changes take effect :

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Comment: No, I tried that, it doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyway. (I did not downvote you.)

Comment: Yes i've seen the downvote; Which distro you are in ?

Comment: Try setting all this values : HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleSuspendKey=suspend 
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend

Comment: Arch Linux. I set everything that remotely makes sense to `suspend`. Restarted the service. Closed the lid for several minutes. Nothing.

Comment: Could you add the output of `systemd-inhibit --list`. Also are you using Gnome ?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Do you know why `journalctl` isn't reporting anything when closing the lid? It appears to me that `systemd` doesn't even know that I closed the lid.

Comment: Yes that's the issue ! Check with `dmesg | grep -i lid` instead ? are you using graphical mode GNOME ?

Comment: Edited my question again.

Answer (score 0):

On my Latitude 5491 I can force close lid action in BIOS, therefore also check your BIOS settings.

Comment: Thanks. I checked every setting my BIOS carefully, but there is nothing related to closing the lid.